# Что происходит при замене myapp.dll на сервере?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Почему не вызывается `Global.asax -> Application_Start` при замене myapp.dll?

Суть в том что есть задания, которые выполняются в `ThreadPool`. Если заменить myapp.dll выбросится `ThreadAbortException`. Я написал небольшой код для перезапуска этих заданий и вызываю его в `Global.asax -> Application_Start`. Но ничего не происходить.

Как можно это реализовать?

вот код запуска

```
    public static void RunAllWorkingOrDivideTasks()
    {
        try
        {
            Task[] tasks = TaskDataManager.GetAllTasks();

            if (tasks.Length > 0)
                foreach (Task task in tasks.Where(e => 
                                        e.status == TaskStatus.active || e.status == TaskStatus.divide))
                {
                    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
                        new WaitCallback(delegate (object state)
                        {
                            Task(task.username, task.taskId);
                        }), null);
                }
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*А откуда у вас возьмутся какие-то задания при старте веб-приложения?*

При замене любого бинарника IIS перезапускает веб-приложение. В ASP.NET это выглядит как выгрузка домена приложений (AppDomain). При этой операции, в том числе, очищаются любые статические поля - в том числе ваш список незавершенных задач.

Задачи, как и любые другие данные в веб-приложении, следует хранить в базе данных.

---

Ах да: после рестарта веб-приложение само по себе не поднимется пока к нему не придет первый запрос.

Попробуйте рецепт вот из этого ответа: [При первом заходе на сайт, который крутится на IIS, сайт очень долго открывается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693223/178779)

Comment: Задания хранят свое состояние на диске локально. 

Task[] tasks = TaskDataManager.GetAllTasks(); получает все состояния.

delegate (object state)
{
     Task(task.username, task.taskId);
}

Получает данные и начинает с ними работать в пуле.

Вопрос в том вызывается ли Global.asax -> Application_Start() при замене бинарника.

Comment: @B.Harholinskiy кажется понял, с чем у вас возникли затруднения. Посмотрите обновление в ответе.