# Автоматический разогрев сервера IIS ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

Как автоматически разогреть сервер IIS? У меня нет доступа к Application Pools, то бишь, у меня нету доступа к настройке IIS, по этому не могу воспользоваться этим способом [Автозапуск ASP.NET приложений](https://habrahabr.ru/post/73272/). Так же [Turning on Start Mode to Always Running in MVC App...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32362150/turning-on-start-mode-to-always-running-in-mvc-application-without-access-to-app) способ с использование сторонних ресурсов которые отправляют серверу сообщения для разогрева с определенной периодичностью не подходит. Слышал, что нужно что-то настроить в web.config'e, но не чего не смог найти.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При первом заходе на сайт, который крутится на IIS, сайт очень долго открывается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693223/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-iis-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f)

Comment: @Андрей Вы правы, только у меня нету доступа к настройки IIS. Мой вопрос состоит в том как сделать то что делается в ответе который Вы привели, только без доступа к IIS.

Comment: А, Вы не пробовали обратиться к тем у кого необходимый доступ есть?

Comment: @Андрей Нет возможности.

Comment: @Puh Тогда прямо говоря это и не ваша задача -- прогревать пул. Вы конечно можете вручную открывать страницы из браузера после деплоя (или деплой тоже не вы делаете) или написать код, который будет открывать нужные страницы, но задача выглядит как-то нелогично.