# Sql server первое обновление очень долгое

Tags: c#, sql-server, производительность, обновление

Доброго времени суток!
Имеется код на C#:

```
try
{
    using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0)))
    {
        using (var sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(Settings.Default.DefaultConnectionString))
        {
            var taDivisions = new DivisionsTableAdapter();

            try
            {
                sqlConnection1.Open();

                taDivisions.Update(data);

                ts.Complete();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (sqlConnection1.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                    sqlConnection1.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    //Log it
    throw;
}
```

Проблема в следующем: при первом выполнении, затраченное время ~ 1 минута ( иногда больше ), притом что в таблице не более 10 строк, и за раз изменяется не более чем 1 строка. Причем время выполнения не зависит вообще никак от таблицы которую обновляем. Запрос выполняется, не отваливается по таймауту, при следующем выполнении - обновление происходит моментально. 
Конфигурация: 2 сервака IIS + SQL Server
Читал что сиквел сервер при обращение кэширует запросы, поэтому при первом обновлении такое происходит. Буду признателен если дадут комментарий, либо реальную причину по которой это может происходить, либо на что обратить внимание. Спасибо!

**UPD.**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин как раз сделан в момент обновления, который занял ~ 1.5 минуты на 1 запись

**UPD. UPD.**

Проблема явно в использовании транзакций.  Если этот же самый код использовать без транзакции все работает очень хорошо. Если применить: проблема та же, первый раз очень долго выполняется.

Comment: Хватает ли ресурсов серверу с SQL? В коде явный глюков нет, поэтому ковыряйте тему "счётчики производительности SQL".

Comment: Начните отсюда: - http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3932406/Top-10-SQL-Server-Counters-for-Monitoring-SQL-Server-Performance.htm Без конкретных цифр вопрос будет похож  на гадание на кофейной гуще.

Comment: Спасибо за статью! Прошелся по основным счетчикам и их описаниям, ничего криминального не нашел. Буду искать дальше в этом направлении, пост обновил скрин приложил

Comment: А вы уверены, что дело именно в первом выполнении кода, а не в старте веб-приложения?

Comment: К сведению: [При первом заходе на сайт, который крутится на IIS, сайт очень долго открывается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693223/178779)

Comment: Именно первое обновление. Очень интересный факт, что все страницы отображают данные из базы ( макс кол-во записей на одной из страниц ~ 600 ), и при этом никаких тормозов нет, т.е. страницы делают обычные селекты и довольно быстро, т.е. можно спокойной ходить по страницам и все хорошо, но как только необходимо обновить одну из строк происходит долгое обновление.

Comment: 1. Отловите первый запрос и план его выполнения. Это как минимум прояснит картину что делает sql-server с Вашим запросом.
2. Взможно при выполнении первого запроса (после входа в приложение), у Вас возникают локи...

Comment: Хм, а зачем вам вообще sqlConnection1 в этом коде?

Comment: @Eminfatullaev - Будет правильней оформить полноценный ответ, удалив его из самого вопроса. А потом принять его.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov понял, спасибо! Первый раз делал пост, в большинстве случаев находил ответы на вопросы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если присмотреться к вашему коду, то в нем есть подвох - вы нигде не используете `sqlConnection1`. Т.е. вы его создаете, открываете и сразу закрываете. В `DivisionsTableAdapter` вы его не передаете.

Вызов `taDivisions.Update(data);` использует какое-то другое соединение. А `sqlConnection1` в коде никак не используется. Но мешает.

По сути вы открываете два соединения в рамках одного Transaction Scope. Это приводит к регистрации транзакции как распределенной, через механизм MS Distributed Transaction Coordinator.

Этот механизм требует настройки Firewall. Кроме того, он требует огромных накладных расходов по сравнению с обычными транзакциями.

Уберите из кода работу с `sqlConnection1` - и он заработает быстро:

```
using (var ts = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(0, 2, 0, 0)))
{
    var taDivisions = new DivisionsTableAdapter();
    taDivisions.Update(data);
    ts.Complete();
}
```

А еще лучше - перестаньте работать через TableAdapter-ы и DataSet-ы - это древний механизм для работы с данными, он не дает ни типизации, ни нормального контроля над выполняемым кодом. Возьмите или Entity Framework (строгая типизация) или Dapper (контроль и скорость).

Answer (score 0):

Разобрались с проблемой, которая сама по себе очевидна и не особо. Проблемой всего оказался брандмауэр Windows, если он отключался все приходило в норму. После настройки правил получили следующую картину:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

6 000 мс как раз тот самый первый запрос, раньше было ~ 95 000 мс. Однако в этой теме я совсем плох, но для меня казалось странным то, что брандмауэр не блокирует запросы, т.к. даже после 90 000 мс они все равно выполнялись. Всем спасибо за советы и помощь!

Comment: Это же скриншот из MS Distributed Transaction Coordinator - жутко тормозного сервиса для распределенных транзакций. Распределенные транзакции - это случай, когда в транзакции участвуют несколько SQL Server-ов. Судя по тому, что у вас включился MS DTC, вы где-то ошиблись в коде - например, работаете с одним SQL Server используя чуть разные ConnectionString.

Comment: Вам стоило бы свести вопрос к минимальному воспроизводимому примеру и все-таки починить проблему, т.к. 700ms на транзакцию - это ужасно долго. По сути, у вас из-за MS DTC все продолжает тормозить, просто уже не так сильно.