# Жизненный цикл ASP MVC приложения и Quartz.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp, quartz

Всем привет! Такой вопрос, у меня есть ASP MVC приложение которое в фоне с помощью Quartz.Net выполняет определенные действия. Однако после запуска сервера, оно функционирует определенное время (может около часа) после последнего обращения к веб-приложению. Опять начинает работать только после того, как опять обратишься к какой либо странице и опять умирает примерно через час. Как сделать, чтобы само веб приложение всегда было активно, даже если нет обращения к View.

работу запускаю так:

```
public static async void Start()
{
        IScheduler scheduler = await StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();await scheduler.Start();
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<ChckNwLsInMail>().Build();
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create() 
                        .WithIdentity("trigger2", "group1")    
                        .StartNow()                            
                        .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x   
                        .WithIntervalInHours(1)        
                        .RepeatForever())                   
                        .Build();
         await scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);  
    }
```

Comment: дайте угадаю, вы используете IIS и в пуле приложений конечно не указали пулу не засыпать? :)

Comment: Возможно, оно? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693223/213987