# Проблемы с Ajax запросами, долго проходит статус pending

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, google-chrome, iis

Всем привет, появилась такая проблема, возникает она не каждый раз, то есть бывает все нормально а бывает выстреливает, сразу оговорю с интернетом все в порядке. После загрузки страницы происходит ajax запрос. Смотрю во вкладку Network  в консоли разработчика, а запрос в статусе pending, спустя некоторое время он все таки загружается. На сервере стоит IIS, на клиенте используется angularjs.
[image: Вкладка Network]

Comment: посмотрите вот этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/693223/179270) мне кажется что Вы найдете там решение

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При первом заходе на сайт, который крутится на IIS, сайт очень долго открывается](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693223/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-iis-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f)

Comment: Это не первый заход на сайт, плюс страница грузится быстро а вот ajax запрос после загрузки страницы медленно (Pending)

Comment: судя по скрину это запрос на получение данных из бд, используете ли orm для работы с бд, если да то какую.

Comment: orm не используется, коннектор npgSql, база данных postgresql

Comment: причем раньше такой проблемы не было и запрос никак не изменялся

Comment: у меня была похожая ситуация, при долгом отсутствии обращений к сайту, *первый запуск* был более долгим чем последующие, так происходила *инициализация* приложения, установление соединения с бд. проблема решилась изменением *Тайм-аут простоя (idleTimeout): 0*. если есть возможность перезапустите пул/или веб сервер и проверьте будет ли первый запрос длительным

Answer (score 2):

Статус pending означает что запрос был отправлен и сервер еще не ответил,
проблема на сервере